# Is there a way to express an "element-wise union" operation on two sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Is there a way to express a binary operation that takes two sets and returns a set containing each of the elements of the first set having been unioned with each element of the 2nd set?

For example, the power set of $X_1 = \{a,b\}$ is:

$\mathcal{P}_{X_1} = \{\emptyset, \{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$

The power set of $X_1 \cup \{c\}$ is:

$\mathcal{P}_{X_1 \cup \{c\}} = \{\emptyset, \{a\},\{b\},\{c\},\{a,b\},\{a,c\},\{b,c\},\{a,b,c\}\}$

but this could also be expressed as:

$\mathcal{P}_{X_1} * \mathcal{P}_{\{c\}}$

where $*$ is the operator that I am asking about.

I know I can just write $\mathcal{P}_{X_1 \cup \{c\}}$ in this instance, but what about for general sets, what if I wanted to do something like:

$X_2 = \{\{a\},\{b\}, \{a,c\}\}$ and $X_3 = \{\emptyset,\{c\},\{a,d\}\}$

and get back:

$X_2 * X_3 = \{\{a\},\{b\}, \{a,c\},\{b,c\},\{a,d\}, \{a,b,d\}, \{a,d,c\}\}$

Is there a general operator that can express this? Or, failing this, how should I go about writing it?

Comment: I have never heard of such an operator being used in literature, but you can always define your own operator.  From your example and the distinct lack of $\{c\}$ being an element, it appears as though you intend it to be $\mathcal{A}*\mathcal{B}=\{A\cup B~:~A\in \mathcal{A},~B\in\mathcal{B}\}$

Comment: Thanks, my background is in computing, so I have never really learned about correct notation. If i was to define the operator as you suggested and use my own symbol, what would you suggest? im thinking either $*$, $\oplus$, or $\uplus$. Do any of those already have very well defined meanings when talking about sets that would confuse the issue if i was to use any of them?

Comment: @guskenny83 It will hard to find a symbol that wasn't used anywhere before. $\oplus$ and $\uplus$ are usually associated with the union of mutually distinct sets. You should also avoid plain copies of known set operators. But besides that, any symbol you can come up with is fine, like $\ast$, $\star$ or maybe $\stackrel{\ast}{\cup}$?

Comment: thanks, i ended up using `\mathaccent\cdot\cup` which gives me a union with a dot in the middle